# React render multiple buttons in for loop from given integer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a progress bar which takes two inputs, `totalSteps` and `activeStep`. I am going to render a number of circles equal to the number of total steps, with the active step being grey.
[image]

I have experience mapping over an array of objects however in this case I don't have an array I am just given an integer.

I am attempting to write a function which returns a `div` in a for loop but this isn't working.

```
const ProgressBar = (props) => {
  const { activeStep, totalSteps } = props;

  const displayProgressBar = () => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalSteps; i++) {
      return <div>Hello</div>;
    }
  };
  return <div className="progressBar">{displayProgressBar()}</div>;
};
```

The above code only renders `Hello` once even if `totalSteps` is 3.  Is there a way to achieve the desired results without creating an array?

Comment: Your function can only `return` once.  If you want multiple elements in that return, you'll need to build up an array or some other data structure and return that.

Comment: as @jmargolisvt said, you can build up an array dynamically first. `let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) arr.push(null); ` and then use `map`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` loop terminates after the first iteration because `return` terminates the function call immediately. You need to accumulate the JSX elements in an array and use that instead. You also don't need the function `displayProgressBar` at all.

```
const ProgressBar = (props) => {
  const { activeStep, totalSteps } = props;

  const steps = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= totalSteps; i++) {
    steps.push(<div>Hello</div>);
  }
  
  return (<div className="progressBar">{ steps }</div>);
};
```

You should probably add an `active` class or something to the `activeStep` item so it is selected, change `steps.push(...)` from above to:

```
steps.push(<div className={ i == activeStep ? "active" : "" }>Hello</div>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You "...have experience mapping over an array..." then this should be a cakewalk; it is exactly the same. If the question more about how to take a number and convert it to an array, and I think it is, then a common pattern is `[...Array(5).keys()]`. Once you've an array you can map it as normal in JSX.

```
const ProgressBar = (props) => {
  const { activeStep, totalSteps } = props;

  const displayProgressBar = () =>
    [...Array(totalSteps).keys()].map((step) => <div key={step}>Hello</div>);

  return <div className="progressBar">{displayProgressBar()}</div>;
};
```

It may be simpler to just inline the array though.

```
const ProgressBar = (props) => {
  const { activeStep, totalSteps } = props;

  return (
    <div className="progressBar">
      {[...Array(totalSteps).keys()].map((step) => {
        // logic to compare against activeStep
        return (
          <div key={step}>Hello</div>
        ))}}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array on the fly just for this

```js
const ProgressBar = (props) => {
  const { activeStep, totalSteps } = props;

  const steps = new Array(totalSteps).fill().map((_,index)=>{
    const stepIndex = index+1;
    const activeClassName = stepIndex === activeStep ? 'active':undefine;
    return <div className={activeClassName}>{stepIndex}</div>
  });
  return <div className="progressBar">{display}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you literally need an array of elements, so what's wrong with creating an array?

```
const ProgressBar = (props) => {
    const { activeStep, totalSteps } = props;

    const steps = (new Array(totalSteps))
        .fill(undefined)
        .map((step, index) => (
            // If the step is active (or past) step, give it a grey background
            <div key={index} style={{ backgroundColor: index + 1 <= activeStep ? 'grey' : 'white' }}>
                {index+1}
            </div>
        ));
    
    return <div className="progressBar">{steps}</div>;
};
```

Something like this will create an array of elements and colour them accordingly