# How To Render MUI Component through For Loop in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

hope you're doing good.

I'm working on an Advent / Chocolate Box Calendar in ReactJS and am trying to iterate over a for Loop for the number of days in December.

I have an issue understanding how to render it to my container in my return statement.

[Code Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYgmA.png)

Here is the code in actual text:

```
const Calendar = () => {
  // For Loop Here for each Day in December (31 Days)
  for (let days = 31; days < array.length; days++) {
    // Grid Item to Be Rendered for each Day
    <Grid item>
      <Box
        sx={{
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
          '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
            opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
          },
        }}
      />
    </Grid>;
  }
};
return (
  <Grid container spacing={1}>
    {/* Want To Generate <Grid item> Here Through for Loop */}
  </Grid>
);
```

I want  to be iterated over 31 times to amount for the total of days in December and render it in my return statement below the Grid component. I've tried to use an array to push the Grid item into and render it but it didn't work.

Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655265/react-render-multiple-buttons-in-for-loop-from-given-integer

Comment: @jspcal Hi, thanks It worked, much appreciated buddy. Take care of yourself man :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for taking your time to help,
I found that this code below worked via @jspcal reference to this link for a more concise answer: [React render multiple buttons in for loop from given integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655265/react-render-multiple-buttons-in-for-loop-from-given-integer)

Here is the code I wrote to make it work:

```
// I added a constant 'box' and set an empty array
  const box = [];

  // I initiated days as 0 instead of 31 and if days are less than 31 then
  // for loop iterates over it until it reaches that number.
  for (let days = 0; days < 31; days++) {
    // Then the code pushes each time it loops to the empty array I initiated.
    box.push(
      <Grid item>
        <Box
          sx={{
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
            '&:hover': {
              backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
              opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
            },
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={1}>
      {/* And here I render the box array */}
      {box}
    </Grid>
  );
```

And here is a snapshot of my code for better visuals:
[image: ![For Loop Code for Rendering MUI Component]

Thanks once again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

In React, it is done using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Check out react docs on [rendering multiple components](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components)

```
 <Grid container spacing={1}>
    {days.map((day) => {
    return (<Grid item key={day}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
          '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
            opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
          },
        }}
      />
    </Grid>)
})
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using the .map method, however it didn't work for me as I was looking to iterate over a number and not an array, will this work as well? Thanks for taking your time to help man

Comment: Technically, a number cant be iterated but a range can be , Something like `[...Array(31).keys()].map()` I guess?

Comment: I found the answer and posted it here, thanks for the help and for the knowledge you've spread :) @agenthunt I ain't the best in JS but sure can use more knowledge regarding it! Take care of yourself man :D